# deploying azure apim policy in prod during business hours

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

i wanted to apply some apim policy to do jwt validation for a specific url.
can i apply this policy during live hours ?
When we hit save in apim policy editor does it anyway will block incoming requests and error ?
please advise.
thanks !

Answer (score 1):

From APIM service itself there would be no problems or downtime. Some seconds after you press save new policy will be enforced and new requests will be processed accordingly.

It's a separate question if the policy is configured correctly and if it will cause any service degradation (for example, some requests may result in 401 response because wrong claim is specified in validate-jwt). This is something you need to ensure yourself.

See about APIM support for revisions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-get-started-revise-api?tabs=azure-portal It may help you to test things safely in production.